# How to subscribe to an event in a task

Tags: c#, multithreading, events, event-handling, task

I am new to multithreading/async processing, so if there is a better way to do this than Task.Factory.StartNew(), please just let me know.

I have 2 projects in my solution. I want to start the 2nd project as a child thread to the first. So, I want the program to start, and the main thread to then start the 2nd project on a child thread. That 2nd program has an event that I would like the main thread to subscribe to, but I do not know how.

Code:

```
public class Program //First project
{
    //Test data

    static TimeSpan formatTime = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0); //Midnight
    static char driveLetter = 'z';
    static Format f = Format.FAT32;
    static string name = "Test";

    //End test data

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //How can I subscribe to DriveFormatNeeded here??
        Task t = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => DriveFormatter.DriveFormatter.Main(formatTime, driveLetter, f, name), TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);

    }
}
```

_

```
public class DriveFormatter //Project 2
{
    public static event EventHandler<CharEventArgs> DriveFormatNeeded;

    public static void Main(TimeSpan formatTime, char driveLetter, Format format, string driveName)
    {
        //Do stuff that will eventually raise DriveFormatNeeded event
    }
```

How can I subscribe to the DriveFormatNeeded event from the main project (where Task.Factory.StartNew() is)? Or am I approaching this completely wrong?

Note: This question is about how to subscribe to events in tasks (or how to design this better from a multi-threading perspective). This question is NOT about the reasons I should not be formatting a drive from C# - I've been down that conversation already.

Thank you in advance!!!

Comment: If you did subscribe "here" then you might have already missed some or all of the events that might have been raised.

Comment: Good point. Edited to reflect subscribing first

Comment: First of all you should be using `Task.Run` and withing run, before you call the `Main` method, subscribe to the event. The question you need to ask yourself is what will you do while the `Main` method is executing? And just so you know, asynchronous is not multithreading. Asynchrony can be achieved without threads.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
//How can I subscribe to DriveFormatNeeded here??
DriveFormatter.DriveFormatter.DriveFormatNeeded += MyHandler;
Task t = ...
```

But there is a lot to think about here. You should in general avoid `static` data and events, Task.Run() in a Console app is doubtful, etc.

Also, try to avoid using the same name for a class and its namespace.